# NSDateFormatter does not formate date correctly ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert date with specific formate and just wanted to get date from passed date as shown below but getting nil
What am I doing wrong?

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: [dicValues valueForKey:@"DateNeeded"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a"];
    NSString *strSubTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

Date i am receiving is : 2016-11-17T23:46:50.35 , 2016-11-28T21:25:20.927 and 2016-11-29T00:00:00

Comment: can you print this [dicValues valueForKey:@"DateNeeded"]

Comment: `[dicValues valueForKey:@"DateNeeded"]` value is?

Comment: Without information how the values in `dicValues` look like, we cannot help. voting for closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

to this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

As in your date string you are receiving MilliSeconds also

**Edit**

This code is working for me, check the date format which you are getting from server

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2016-11-28T21:25:20.927"];
    if (date == nil) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2016-11-28T21:25:20.927"];
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a"];
    NSString *strSubTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

Comment: date i received is : 2016-11-28T21:25:20.927

Comment: Updated answer Check now

Comment: hey different records send me different date like 2016-11-17T23:46:50.35  , 2016-11-28T21:25:20.927 and 2016-11-29T00:00:00. problem comes for 2016-11-29T00:00:00. ur solution works fine for  (2016-11-17T23:46:50.35  , 2016-11-28T21:25:20.927)   .... issue with 2016-11-29T00:00:00

Comment: @user2813740 check my edit, here if you get nil date then change the dateFormatter's dateFormat

Comment: thank you, it was mismatched for different records....you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

`[dicValues valueForKey: @"DateNeeded"]` is either nil or does not match the specified format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`.

Comment: date i received : 2016-11-28T21:25:20.927

Answer (score 0):

First check that date you receive, is in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format. If not then make this format according to date you received.

For Example, you received date `29/11/16`, then your code will be like this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: [dicValues valueForKey:@"DateNeeded"]];
```

Once you get date, then convert it any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

Comment: This is an answer. If op fixes this, his code will work.

Comment: Well, he didn't when I wrote this answer.

Comment: And now he includes the 'T' token

Comment: An answer is not defined by it's size. And IMO code is our lingua franca.

Comment: it is clear enough, as OP knows where the code yields nil. But if you find my answer so bad: go ahead, vote it down and write your own. You can be as rambling as you wish.

Comment: or even better: as you have enough reputation you can alter my question, I would be very thankful.